# How to fetch the value of a dropdown in XSL (SobiPro plugin in Joomla)?

Tags: php, xml, xslt, joomla, sobipro

I am trying to make some modifications to `SobiPro` plugin in a Joomla site.
Ref:[Site Url](http://www.lenmedhealth.com/index.php?option=com_sobipro&task=search&sid=55)
We have implemented SobiPro search feature. There are 2 dropdowns.

1. Specialty/Category of doctor
2. Hospital Name

In the Specialty dropdown, different specialities are listed down in the following format;

- Select Category

  - Dentist
  - Psychologist
  - Anaesthetist

When a specific category is selected the rsearch results are getting displayed correctly. What I am trying to do is to make a different display when a user 'doesn't select a default category'.

i.e - A user selects 'Select category' in first dropdown and 'Hospital name' in second dropdown.

A layout with the 'Specialty' as heading in top row. Then all the doctors in that specialty will be displayed under that heading.

For this to work, I need to fetch the value of 'Specialty/Category' dropdown. How can I do it in XSL?

```
<select name="field_speciality" id="field_speciality" class="" style="width: 200px;">
    <option selected="selected" value="0">Select Category</option>
        <option disabled="disabled" value="55">- Doctors</option>
        <option value="74">Dentist</option>
        <option value="262">Psychologist</option>
        <option value="118">Pulmonologist</option>
</select>
```

How can I implement the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done the modifications using 'Muenchian method'.
I am attaching a reference link here incase anyone have a similar requirement.
Ref: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml